# Add an object to a json file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Append an object to a existing dictionary embedded in a json file.

I have a sample json file which I am reading using below code. Please check the code and sample json file here.

```
with open('sample.json') as fp:
  dictObj = json.load(fp)
```

```
{
    "versions" : [
        {
            "version" : "0.0",
            "termsTranslations" : {
                "en" : "my rev"
            },
            "createDate" : "2019-10-28T04:20:11.320Z"
        }
        ]
         "active" : "0.3",
        "uiConfig" : {
            "displayName" : "We've updated our terms",
            "purpose" : "You must accept the updated terms in order to proceed.",
            "buttonText" : "Accept"
        }
        
}
```

I intend to add the below constructed object named newobj with value as below(has arabic text) to the sample.json file.

```
{'version': 0.4, 'termsTranslations': '{"ar": "<p dir="rtl"align="right">يرجى قراءة التعليم</p>","createDate": "2023-06-20T12:32:22Z"}'
```

The resultant sample.json file should like below:

```
{
    "versions" : [
        {
            "version" : "0.0",
            "termsTranslations" : {
                "en" : "my rev"
            },
            "createDate" : "2019-10-28T04:20:11.320Z"
        },
        {'version': 0.4, 
                'termsTranslations': '{"ar": "<p dir="rtl"align="right">يرجى قراءة التعليمات الهامة التالية والشروط والأحكام قبل التسجيل في خدمة ساب نت والساب موبايل</p>',
                'createDate': '2023-06-20T12:32:22Z'}
        ]
        "active" : "0.3",
        "uiConfig" : {
            "displayName" : "We've updated our terms",
            "purpose" : "You must accept the updated terms in order to proceed.",
            "buttonText" : "Accept"
        }
        
}
```

Is there a way this can be achieved in python using any of the library's?

Comment: Btw `termsTranslations` value isn't valid JSON

Comment: the newobj contents is incorrect. The dictionary is not closed. review the code  @Karan

Answer (score 1):

You'd simply append to the list

```
dictObj['versions'].append(new_version)
```

Comment: @OneCricketer this worked but my arabic text between p tags is not showing up right value.
termsTranslations": {"ar": "<p dir=\"rtl\"align=\"right\">\u064a\u0631\u062c\u0649 \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0621\u0629

Comment: Python writes JSON files as utf8, so you're **seeing** Unicode control characters, but the file should be **stored** the way you want

Answer (score 0):

After reading the JSON file, you can just do the following:

```py
newVersion = {'version': 0.4, 'termsTranslations': {'ar': '<p dir="rtl"align="right">يرجى قراءة التعليم</p>','createDate': '2023-06-20T12:32:22Z'}
dictObj['versions'].append(newVersion)
with open("sample.json") as fp:
    fp.write(json.dumps(dictObj))
```

Answer (score 0):

Appending it would be:

```
dictObj['versions'].append(newobj)
```

I recommend you replace the double quote for `&#x22;` : The browsers will read them without problem. Specially if you need a valid JSON: JSON format does not accept APOSTROPHE instead of QUOTATION MARK ([see](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=0x&unicodeinhtml=hex)).

The final JSON, should look like this:

```
{
    "versions": [
        {
            "version": "0.0",
            "termsTranslations": {
                "en": "my rev"
            },
            "createDate": "2019-10-28T04:20:11.320Z"
        },
        {
            "version": 0.4,
            "termsTranslations": "{&#x22;ar&#x22;: &#x22;<p dir=&#x22;rtl&#x22;align=&#x22;right&#x22;>يرجى قراءة التعليمات الهامة التالية والشروط والأحكام قبل التسجيل في خدمة ساب نت والساب موبايل</p>",
            "createDate": "2023-06-20T12:32:22Z"
        }
    ],
    "active": "0.3",
    "uiConfig": {
        "displayName": "We've updated our terms",
        "purpose": "You must accept the updated terms in order to proceed.",
        "buttonText": "Accept"
    }
}
```

You also had a typo after the dictionary. There was no comma.